# Jest how to assert that function is not called

Tags: jestjs

In Jest there are functions like `tobeCalled` or `toBeCalledWith` to check if a particular function is called.
Is there any way to check that a function is not called?

Comment: Please check the documentation, one of the two examples for `toBeCalled` is how to check a function has *not* been called: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tohavebeencalled

Answer (score 297):

Just use `not`.

```js
expect(mockFn).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
```

See the [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalled)

Answer (score 32):

`not` did not work for me, throwing a `Invalid Chai property: toHaveBeenCalled`

But using `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` with zero does the trick:

`expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)`

Comment: The question is about Jest

Comment: What do you mean? My answer is a solution using jest

Comment: I imagine he means the `Chai` error. But mabe Jest uses (or once used) Chai under the hood?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the documentation from jest:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-property

> All mock functions have this special .mock property, which is where data about how the function has been called and what the function returned is kept. The .mock property also tracks the value of this for each call, so it is possible to inspect this as well: [...]
>
> These mock members are very useful in tests to assert how these functions get called, instantiated, or what they returned:

```
// The function was called exactly once
expect(someMockFunction.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
```

Or...

```
// The function was not called
expect(someMockFunction.mock.calls.length).toBe(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Jest (22.x and onwards) collect quite decent statistics of mock functions calls, just check out [their docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions).

The `calls` property shows you the number of calls, the arguments passed to the mock, the result returned out of it and whatnot. You can access it directly, as a property of `mock` (e.g. in a way how @Christian Bonzelet suggested in his answer):

```
// The function was called exactly once
expect(someMockFunction.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);

// The first arg of the first call to the function was 'first arg'
expect(someMockFunction.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('first arg');

// The second arg of the first call to the function was 'second arg'
expect(someMockFunction.mock.calls[0][1]).toBe('second arg');
```

I personally prefer this way as it gives you more flexibility and keeps code cleaner in case if you test for different inputs that produce a different number of calls.

However, you can also use shorthand aliases for Jest's `expect` since recently ([spy matchers aliases PR](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/5826)). I guess [`.toHaveBeenCalledTimes`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#tohavebeencalledtimesnumber) would suit fine here:

```
test('drinkEach drinks each drink', () => {
  const drink = jest.fn();
  drinkEach(drink, ['lemon', 'octopus']);
  expect(drink).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2); // or check for 0 if needed
});
```

In rare cases, you might even want to consider writing your own fixture that'd do the counting. It could be useful if you're heavy on conditioning or working with state, for example.

Hope this helps!